# Using a variable to sort multidimensional php array (usort)

Tags: php, variables, multidimensional-array, anonymous-function, usort

There are a few posts here on SO that concern with sorting multidimensional arrays in php and I can get it to work fine when using:

```
usort($list, function($a, $b)
            {
                return $a['content_id'] <=> $b['content_id'];
            }
        );
```

But I can't find any reference to using a variable to sort with. When I try to use one, I get an error. eg in this example:

```
    $sortVariable='content_id';
    usort($list, function($a, $b)
            {
                return $a[$sortVariable] <=> $b[$sortVariable];
            }
        );
```

It doesn't work and I am not sure why - I get the 'Undefined variable' error. Looking for help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). `$sortVariable` is not available inside of your function. To make it available to your closure use the [`use` language construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$sortVariable='content_id';
usort($list, function($a, $b) use ($sortVariable) {
    return $a[$sortVariable] <=> $b[$sortVariable];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a scope issue, this is great